# How to know the direction of the text?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I need to know the direction of a text depending on the language of the keyboard when typing in a UITextView. For example, if the user is typing in english, then the direction will be "left to right" and if the user is typing in arabic, "right to left". I need that value without doubts and avoiding to hardcoding a matching between each language and its text direction.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out this method from [UITextInput Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (UITextWritingDirection)baseWritingDirectionForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position inDirection:(UITextStorageDirection)direction
```

This returns a constant that represents a writing direction (for example, left-to-right or right-to-left)

UITextView implements such protocol.