# Detecting UITextView text direction

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview, right-to-left, direction

I support both Left-to-Right and Right-to-Left in my application.
How can I detect text direction in my UITextView/UITextField?

- I can't use device's locale because user can have multiple keyboards with languages with different read/write directions.
- I suppose UITextInputTraits is also no use because Apple's documentation said that controls only additional keyboard buttons and not the ones with letters.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know the direction of the text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305791/how-to-know-the-direction-of-the-text)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation on UITextInput:  The below method will return the direction of the text.

```
func baseWritingDirection(for position: UITextPosition, in direction: UITextStorageDirection) -> UITextWritingDirection {
    <#code#>
}
```

Official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/1614502-basewritingdirection